# Divide a number into powers of two?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Here is and example for the problem. Suppose I have two numbers int basic_block and int block.
basic block is some number that is a power of 2 and block is some number that is divisible by basic_block. So consider this example where basic_block = 128 and block = 640. I need to divide the block into different numbers that are powers of two. The two numbers should be grater than or equal to basic_block. So I would have something like 512 and 128. In this case I should get the first the number as 512 since it the largest power of 2 less than 640.

Is there a function that I can use to do this?

Comment: "I need to divide the block into **two** numbers that are powers of two" <- This isn't always possible. Your example is a lucky exception.

Comment: I meant different numbers not just two. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, you can extract the lowest power of two from a number with `x & -x` (make sure `x` is unsigned). You then remove that power of two from `x` and then extract the next one, and so on. But I'm not really sure what you want here..

Comment: @user2731223: It's possible if and only if the popcount of the number is two :-)

Comment: Try the logarithm with base 2 and floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the powers of two until your result is bigger than `block`. If you're lucky, the result of `(block - 2^(n-1))` with `(2^n)>block` is another power of two, if not, rerun this function with `block-2^(n-1)` until `block` is 1...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the **`C`** math library to do the following:

```
function int getBlockSize(int value) {
  return (int)(floor(log2(value)));
}
```

Don't forget to link to the math library with the `-lm` compiler flag

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function that I can use to do this?

Yes, the one you write to do it.

You basically will need to either recursively break down a number into the powers of 2 that can sum to it, or do it in a loop.